# Would water flow in the following system?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, cooling

[image]

Would water flow in the following system?

Comment: It depends what goes on the box on the right. Is there a punp? Is the water being heated or cooled, etc. More details are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends!

Longer answer:
If the temperature of the water in the tank is uniform and the peltier is able to reduce the temperature of the water, ther will be a flow of water. At least for some time.

The flow of water will stop when:

- the water in the tank becomes layered (warm water at the top, cold, denser water at the bottom) and the force due to cooling of the water at the peltier is not enough to ovorcome the force needed to push the layer stack upwards
- When the peltier can't generate enough of a cooldown effect anymore
- When the water freezes

To make the system more efficient install the cooling element higher up so the column of cold water gets higher and can apply more force.